# Proving Identity: $P_{12}\Omega(X_1,P_1;X_2,P_2)P_{12}=\Omega(X_2,P_2;X_1,P_1)$ where $P_{12}$ is exchange Operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators

I'm stuck on the problem given in Exercise 10.3.5 on R.Shankar's Quantum Mechanics book. The chapter name is "Systems with N degrees of freedom".

Consider the exchange operator whose action on the $\Omega $ basis is
$$P_{12}|\omega_1,\omega_2\rangle=|\omega_2,\omega_1\rangle$$
i.e. exchange the labels.

I'm trying to prove $$P_{12}\Omega(X_1,P_1;X_2,P_2)P_{12}=\Omega(X_2,P_2;X_1,P_1)$$

What I have done so far
$$P_{12}\Omega(X_1,P_1;X_2,P_2)P_{12} |x_1,x_2\rangle=P_{12}\Omega(X_1,P_1;X_2,P_2)|x_2,x_1\rangle$$

I'm not sure what to do now as I don't know the form of the operator. Can anyone help me, how do I proceed further?

Comment: What is $\Omega(X_1,P_1;X_2,P_2)$ and how does it relate to $\vert \omega_1\omega_2\rangle$?  Note also that in your first equation you may be subscript mixed up as there’s no label exchanged on the RHS.

Comment: There is no information about $ \Omega$ given. And I have changed the first equation.

Comment: Can you provide the source?

Comment: It's from R. Shankar 's Quantum Mechanics book. Chapter 10 Exercise 10.3.5.